# Playing audio file using HTML 5 and jsp

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans-7

I am trying to play an audio file, it works when I have a .html file but when I am running the same code in a .jsp file the file cannot be played. I am using Netbeans IDE. Could someone please point out the mistake, Here is the jsp code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <audio controls>

        <source src="C:\Users\Desktop\1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

    </audio>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `src` attribute should not be the file location of the audio file. Instead, it should be the URL for the file. So in your case, try

```
<audio controls>
     <source src="http://localhost:8080/PathToMp3/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

where **`http://localhost:8080/PathToMp3/1.mp3`** is the url of your mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <audio controls>
     <source src="http://localhost:8080/PathToMp3/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

if it's not working use this

```
 <embed src="">
```